# Connection between R and Python

Tags: python, windows, r

I'm just trying to connect to R via Python, with the following code. However it throws an error when initializing R

```
> from win32com.client import Dispatch
> sc=Dispatch("StatConnectorSrv.StatConnector")
> sc.Init("R")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<COMObject StatConnectorSrv.StatConnector>", line 2, in Init
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None,
 0, -2147221485), None)

> print(sc.Evaluate("2+2"))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<COMObject StatConnectorSrv.StatConnector>", line 2, in Evaluate
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 282, in
_ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes
) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None,
 0, -2147221500), None)
```

Comment: Did you know about rpy2? (http://rpy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: no I don't. TBH Using Python was to try and understand a larger problem with my install of StatDCOM - which I have to use to get R working with QlikView

Comment: Although I always hate to say "try another language", in this case… VB# generally gives much more information error messages than Python with win32com when you're trying to debug COM installation errors. (Pre-.NET VB was even better, if that's an option.)

Comment: If you want to stick with Python, you have to convert those numbers to hex (80020009 and 80040004) and look them up in MSDN help (or via google, etc.)

Comment: From a quick search, 0x80020009 (`DISP_E_EXCEPTION`) just means that IDispatch failed for "some reason", and in this case the reason is probably the 0x80040004 (`OLE_E_NOCONNECTION`), which seems to usually be caused by a corrupted COM registry. (The page to search for the names is [HRESULT values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx), but the descriptions there aren't often enough to go on.)